# How do I println when I reach a certain char in my string?

Tags: java, encryption, char

So essentially I am reading in from a txt file and writing out to a new file an encrypted copy. The professor said at the end of every line add a 0 at the end of it so that your program knows that is the end of that line. An example would be

THECATCRIES0

THEDOGCRIES0

The problem is that no matter what I tweak to my code I can not appear to print the additional line, so my copied encrypted version all prints on one really long line. My code is as follows

```
            for(int n = 0; n < first.length()-1; n+=2) {
                 String character = first.substring(n, n + 2);
                 alpha = character.charAt(0);
                 bravo = character.charAt(1);
                 firstLetter = (int)(alpha) - 65;
                 secondLetter = (int)(bravo) - 65;
                 File newFile = new File("newcopy.txt");

                 PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(newFile, true));
                 if(secondLetter < 10){
                     write.print(firstLetter);
                     write.print(0);
                     write.print(secondLetter);
                     if(Character.isDigit(bravo) || Character.isDigit(alpha)){
                         write.println();
                     }

                 } else {
                     write.print(firstLetter);
                     write.print(secondLetter);
                     if(Character.isDigit(bravo)|| Character.isDigit(alpha)){
                         write.println();
                     }

                 }write.close();
```

When I googled it I found online the isDigit method that returns a Boolean which should return true because there is a 0 at the end. I tried placing this method in both if/else statements and I also tried using a regular System.out.println(), which I don't think would work because I am using PrintWriter to write my things into the new file. I should also note the stuff I am "encrypting" is in all caps. That is to get the numbers for my encrypted letters when I convert them to numbers.

Comment: How about `String.endsWith` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)

Comment: The only issue with that is that I need to print the line only when it reaches the 0. If I use that method I believe it will print a line every time through not just at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
try(Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(newFile.toURI()))) {
    stream.forEach(s -> {if(s.endsWith("0")) System.out.println(s);});
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```